# How to use jQuery in Google Sitemaps and is it allowed

Tags: jquery, xml, seo, sitemap

How do I use jQuery in a Google Sitemap and most importantly does it violate the specifications rules or will it be blocked by Google because of the jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you could use an xslt style. But whether or not you can use javascript inside I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Google Sitemaps are XML files. How would you use javascript in an XML file?

Comment: for styling and display purposes. I know I can use css but need more control over visual elements.

Comment: Are you talking about a Google MAP and styling that? Or are you talking about a Google SITEMAP which helps Google make your site more optimized for SEO/SEM?

Comment: the latter, as in sitemap.xml

Comment: @Julian, you could use xsl. @The Keeper of the Cheese, technically this is more a comment than an answer, but I agree with the underlying sentiment of **why?** so I'm up-voting you anyway.

Comment: I can't figure out how to add a comment to an unanswered question. I didn't want to make it an answer. I appreciate the vote.

Comment: @David Thomas, now that I look into XSL I see a handy "transform" feature that I really need. At first glance, I figured XSL was just a version of CSS for XML files.

Comment: @Julian that's fair, that was my first thought too when I first looked at it =) (my second thought was along the lines of "life's too short"...) @The Keeper of the Cheese, you can't add comments yet because your rep is still < 50 (I think that's the threshold, from memory). Once you get over 50 (or whatever it really is) then you'll see an 'add comment' link below questions and answers.